# How can I import a File.swift into ViewController.h and viceversa?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, import

I tried to make a file .swift to change the color from the navigation bar in a but when I tried to import the File.swift in the ViewController it shows me an error.

------- code--------

```
//Esta clase se creo para dar color a la NavViewController por medio de su valor en RGB
import UIKit

class NavViewController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        //Se divide el valor RGB entre 255.0

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 110/255.0, green: 192/255.0, blue: 238/255.0, alpha: 1.0)



        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
```

error says : Expected ; after top level declaration

Comment: What does that file contain? Is it a class?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the official documents from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

**Use Swift in Objective-C**

you need to rely on an Xcode-generated header file to expose those files to Objective-C. This automatically generated file is an Objective-C header that declares the Swift interfaces in your target.

1. In the app target `building settings`, you could find your `Product Module Name`.
2. In Objective-C file, `#import "<ProductModuleName>-Swift.h"`

**Use Objective-C in Swift**

1. Create bridge file, Choosing File > New > File > (iOS or OS X) > Source > Header File. The naming convention is `<ProductModuleName>-Bridging-Header.h` (Also, you could create a `Swift` in pure `Objective-C` project and XCode will prompt whether you need a bridge file)
2. Import **Objective-C** file you want to use into the bridge file.
3. Use it directly in **Swift** Code.

Answer (score 1):

In `appName-Bridging-Header.h` you need to import required .h file and they will be available in swift code

And in Objective-C file you need to import the generated header `module_name-Swift.h` which contains all the swift classes. This way swift classes will be available in objective c.